How to configure Visual Studio Code for FreePascal (launch.json)
I'm relatively new to VS Code. I'm trying to configure it to run FreePascal on Windows. I'm trying to follow the instructions of Mr Bee from May 2018. I think this error is from the launch.json:
The terminal process failed to launch: Starting directory (cwd) "C:\Users\myusername\Projects\TestProjects\FpTest\ C:\Users\myusername\Projects\TestProjects\FpTest " does not exist.

I don't understand why it is repeating the folder that contains the source file. This is my configuration:
{ 
    "type" : "lldb" ,
    "request" : "launch" ,
    "name" : " LLDB Debugger " ,
    "cwd" : "${workspaceFolder}", 
    "program" : " .build/debug/${fileBasenameNoExtension} " ,
    "args" : [],
    "terminal" : " integrated " ,
    "preLaunchTask" : " fpc: Build Debug " ,
    "postDebugTask" : " fpc: Remove Build Files "
}

I removed the ${workspaceFolder from cwd, but to no avail. What can I do to get this working?

The issue you're encountering is likely due to an extra space in the cwd and program fields.
{
    "type": "lldb",
    "request": "launch",
    "name": "LLDB Debugger",
    "cwd": "${workspaceFolder}", 
    "program": "${workspaceFolder}/.build/debug/${fileBasenameNoExtension}",
    "args": [],
    "terminal": "integrated",
    "preLaunchTask": "fpc: Build Debug",
    "postDebugTask": "fpc: Remove Build Files"
}


Thank you for your response! I removed all the leading and trailing spaces before and after the actual values resp. Also in the file tasks.json, but unfortunately, I'm still getting the same error.

Hmm, after pressing the reload / refresh button I'm getting a step further! I understand that the " current working folder" is now recognised. I guess that after installation, some extensions needed it in order to work. Thanks!

In the meantime I have installed the GDB debugger, because it's very difficult to get the LLDB installed on Windows. It means that I have tried to use the same configuration but with "LLDB" replaced by "GDB". Unfortunately to no avail. I tried many other things as well, but no success either. Is there anybody out there who has advice for me?
